# How to config more than 1 IP address using debian preseed.cfg

Tags: debian, preseed

How to get the network interface name and use it while adding new line of IP configuration to file /etc/network/interface using preseed command?

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
  in-target sed -i "s/^#Port 22\$/Port 39000/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config; \
  in-target sed -i "s/^#PermitRootLogin.*\$/PermitRootLogin yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config; \
  in-target systemctl restart sshd.service; \
  in-target var=$(ip -o link show | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' | tail -n 1); \
  in-target sed -i "/dns-search unassigned-domain/c\iface $var:1 inet static\naddress 192.168.1.40\nnetmask 255.255.255.0\ngateway 192.168.1.1\ndns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4\ndns-search unassigned-domain" /etc/network/interfaces; \
  in-target systemctl restart networking; \
  in-target ifup $var && ifup $var:1; \
true
```

According to my configuration in preseed.cfg, the /etc/ssh/sshd_config is able to be modified, new lines are added to /etc/network/interfaces also, but the command,

```
in-target var=$(ip -o link show | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' | tail -n 1); \
```

is not working, the output should be iface [interface name] inet static, however there is only iface  inet static without the interface name.

Please help.